# Is there a consensus of how find_package() behaves in CMake?

Tags: cmake

Normally `find_package(foo)` will define

```
${FOO_FOUND}
${FOO_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
${FOO_LIBRARIES}
```

But only `${FOO_FOUND}` is mentioned in CMake Docs. And some libs don't follow this rule. Such as Glog.

There are two mode of `find_package()`. One is Module Mode, which uses `FindFoo.cmake`. Another is Config Mode, which uses `foo-config.cmake`.

`foo-config.cmake` is provided by foo's maintainer, while `FindFoo.cmake` maybe written by someone else. Am I Right ? Is there a consensus of how to define variables among developers ?

"Imported targets" is a new feature after CMake 2.6, which can provide a better way to find libs. So should the use of `${FOO_INCLUDE_DIRS}` `${FOO_LIBRARIES}` be considered as a legacy way ? Or should them be keet for compatibility ?

Two links I found that suggest to define these three variables:

https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file
https://coderwall.com/p/qej45g/use-cmake-enabled-libraries-in-your-cmake-project-iii

Comment: Just a hint: you're linking to an outdated Wiki page. [`cmake-packages`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) is what you can refer to. It more or less describes the consensus. There are several tutorial examples out there like [this](https://github.com/forexample/package-example) from [@ruslo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2288008/ruslo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to config files and find macros, there is no really enforced schema of which variables are be set. Generally, every author can decide which variables to define and how they are called. For the provided find marcos, these variables are usually documented in the cmake manual, e.g. as for [boost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html).

One example for a common pitfall from this that I have seen over the years is that some packages define `*_INCLUDE_DIRS` while others use singular `*_INCLUDE_DIR`.

So, to my mind, the best you can do is to browse through the provided find macros in the cmake documentation and derive the de factor consensus from there.

Comment: I found that CMake's Imported target is really a powerful tool. We don't need to define `*_INCLUDE_DIRS` or `*_LIBRARIES` any more, include directories and c++ preprocesser will be added automatically to target when we do [target_link_libraries()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) with a Imported target.

Comment: The problem is the compatibility with old packages, which is really a mess.